# I want to translate morse code into words. Still have a small problem

Tags: java, string, loops, switch-statement, morse-code

So Im splitting at " ". Problem is that morsecode is dividing each word by three spaces. "   ".

So when Im translating it always prints out each word written together without spaces inbetween.

Heres what I have. Im using StringBuilder for obvious reasons.

```
public class MorseCodeDecoder {
public static String decode(String morseCode) {
    String word = "";
    String character = "";

    //count how much space is inbetween lines.
    StringBuilder codeTwo = new StringBuilder();
    String[] output = morseCode.split(" ");


    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
```

Inside here I tried to do an seperate if-statement. if morseCode contains three spaces back to back append one space.

```
//if(morseCode.contains("   ")) codeTwo.append(" "); (or \\s maybe, doesnt matter)


        switch (output[i]) {
            case "   ":
                codeTwo.append(" ");
                break;
            case ".-":
                codeTwo.append("A");
                break;
            case "-...":
                codeTwo.append("B");
                break;
            case "-.-.":
                codeTwo.append("C");
                break;
            case "-..":
                codeTwo.append("D");
                break;
            case ".":
                codeTwo.append("E");
                break;
            case "..-.":
                codeTwo.append("F");
                break;
            case "--.":
                codeTwo.append("G");
                break;
            case "....":
                codeTwo.append("H");
                break;
            case "..":
                codeTwo.append("I");
                break;
            case ".---":
                codeTwo.append("J");
                break;
            case "-.-":
                codeTwo.append("K");
                break;
            case ".-..":
                codeTwo.append("L");
                break;
            case "--":
                codeTwo.append("M");
                break;
            case "-.":
                codeTwo.append("N");
                break;
            case "---":
                codeTwo.append("O");
                break;
            case ".--.":
                codeTwo.append("P");
                break;
            case "--.-":
                codeTwo.append("Q");
                break;
            case ".-.":
                codeTwo.append("R");
                break;
            case "...":
                codeTwo.append("S");
                break;
            case "-":
                codeTwo.append("T");
                break;
            case "..-":
                codeTwo.append("U");
                break;
            case "...-":
                codeTwo.append("V");
                break;
            case ".--":
                codeTwo.append("W");
                break;
            case "-..-":
                codeTwo.append("X");
                break;
            case "-.--":
                codeTwo.append("Y");
                break;
            case "--..":
                codeTwo.append("Z");
                break;
        }
    }
    return codeTwo.toString();
  }
 }
```

For input: .... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .
Expected output: "HEY JUDE"

Comment: Can you provide an expected input and expected output, as well as your current input and current output as an example?

Comment: Why don't you replace all triple spaces in the string with single space. Also, in your for loop, after the switch part, append a space so that the result has the words separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex instead of splitting by spaces...
Something like this pattern:

```
([._])+\s*
```

Explanation: We're looking for at least 1 instance of a dot (.) or underscore (_) followed by zero or more spaces...

I've used it over this example:

```
._ _... _._   .._ ..._ .__
```

Which is: ABC UVW

I'm not near a computer - but the program should look something like that:

```
public static String decode(final String morseCode) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(morseCode);

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        builder.append(getLetter(matcher.group().trim()));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Assuming `getLetter()` is your switch case.

More of a nitpick - instead of using this massive switch case you should use a static map that will contain the mapping between the symbols and letters and initialize it on the static constructor ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html )

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that since your letters and your words share a delimiter, when you split by a single space, you are effectively removing your word spacing completely, so the switch statement never gets a chance to read them. There are two solutions I can imagine. The first is the code I have below. Since morse code only uses a specific set of characters, you can simply replace your word delimiter with a character outside of the alphabet and then detect that instead. For the second possible solution, if you would like to keep the integrity of the input, then you could also first split by the three spaces to separate each word, and then use your switch statement on each word, appending a space after each word has been successfully translated. This would require two loops (outer loop for the words and inner loop for the letters).

```
public class MorseCodeDecoder {
    public static String decode(String morseCode) {
        String word = "";
        String character = "";

        //count how much space is inbetween lines.
        StringBuilder codeTwo = new StringBuilder();
        morseCode.replace("   ", "|");
        String[] output = morseCode.split(" ");


        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            switch (output[i]) {
                case "|":
                    codeTwo.append(" ");
                    break;
                case ".-":
                    codeTwo.append("A");
                    break;
                //etc.
        }
        return codeTwo.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that letters split by single space while words split by 3 spaces

Comment: SO took out the extra spaces from your example, hence the confusion. I understand now, one second and I'll update a solution.

Comment: Updated with a more proper solution.